# Using axis and angle of rotation in glrotate

Tags: opengl

I followed the question here [Quaternion math for rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764313/quaternion-math-for-rotation) to get an angle of rotation and the axis around which I need to rotate, My question is how do I pass the angle and axis as an argument to glrotate()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the axis is defined by the variables x, y, z, and the rotation angle is in the variable angle, then it's as simple as [glRotatef(angle, x, y, z)](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/rotate.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `double` version is

```
glRotated(angle,x,y,z)
```

The `float` version is

```
glRotatef(angle, x, y, z)
```

The angle must be in degrees, so convert it to degrees first if it is in radians.